# Mounting USB volume in Docker Toolbox for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-toolbox

In Ubuntu, I can mount a USB volume with the command

```
docker run --privileged /dev/bus/usb/:/dev/bus/usb/ -d docker-image-name
```

What would be its equivalent line using Docker Toolbox for Windows ?

Comment: This answer helped me solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/51063839/9940118

Answer (score 1):

I have this same exact question.
Currently using --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb yields a "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" error in the app when trying to use the USB